# visudo How can I run script as root without password

Tags: unix

I have a very simple script that needs to run as su (root) without using a password.

**Script**

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /Applications/data_vis/
sudo chown -R Fabulous:admin .
```

I have decided to use permissions and visudo(8) to make it possible, for the script above to run with out a password.

**Permissions**

```
sudo chown root:wheel take_ownership.sh

sudo chmod 4755 take_ownership.sh
```

**Extract from visudo file**

```
# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL) ALL
%admin  ALL=(ALL) ALL
%Fabulous  ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /Applications/data_vis/take_ownership.sh, 
%ALL ALL=NOPASSWD: /Applications/data_vis/take_ownership.sh 

# Uncomment to allow people in group wheel to run all commands
%wheel  ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

I have tried many variations and a lot of the questions on this sight. However I must be missing something as it is not obvious to what I am missing or doing incorrect.

Any practical specific solutions welcome. I am using a bash shell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sudo is used to give non-root users root priviledges for a couple of tasks.

Supposing "take_ownership.sh" is the script, which contents is listed above, the
task of gaining root priviledges is doubled:
With sudo inside the script and by setting the script suid bit and setting the ownership 
to root:wheel.

This isn't necessary.

In general for security reasons setuid scripts are to prevented.
Therefore a shell may prevent the execution of such script generally.

Another reason for the problem may unsufficient rights on /Applications/data_vis/.
for the user, who executs the script (if the setuid bit was cleared as suggested
above).

Reduce the script to
sudo chown -R Fabulous:admin /Applications/data_vis

Remove the setuid bit.

Execute the script as non-root-user.

If it fails, check with dmesg for kernel entries.

Furthermore from the sudo manpage (Linux):

There is no easy way to prevent a user from gaining a root shell if that user is allowed to
run arbitrary commands via sudo.  Also, many programs (such as editors) allow the user to
run commands via shell escapes, thus avoiding sudo's checks.  However, on most systems it is
possible to prevent shell escapes with the sudoers(5) plugin's noexec functionality.

It is not meaningful to run the cd command directly via sudo, e.g.,

```
  $ sudo cd /usr/local/protected
```

since when the command exits the parent process (your shell) will still be the same.  Please
see the EXAMPLES section for more information.

Running shell scripts via sudo can expose the same kernel bugs that make setuid shell
scripts unsafe on some operating systems (if your OS has a /dev/fd/ directory, setuid shell
scripts are generally safe).